# Django "Model.objects.create()" linking two fields/relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-3.1

kindly correct me with the tittle if it is wrong or misleading, thanks.

**I am very new to Django Python. I am using Django 3.1.1.**

My question is about the `"Model".objects.create()`, I use it with ajax to save or create data in my `Logger` model.

Question: How can I link the `Logger.userprofile` to `UserProfile.user` using `Logger.objects.create()` or what is the next thing to do to linked the two fields?

My `UserProfile` model is already linked to the `User` model via `OneToOneField` but was saving data using `form.save()`, and this was successful. below is what I have constructed so far by following numerous tutorials.

This is already working and it is creating data in my Model, I just need to add the link between the `UserProfile` and the `Logger` for the sake of easy identification of the log created.

Log is created in the `Logger` Model via qrcode scan.

**Views.py**

```
def processQRCode(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
            qrcoderes = request.POST['qrcoderes']
            logged_in = request.POST['logged_in']
            logged_in_location = request.POST['logged_in_location']

            Logger.objects.create(
                qrcode_uuid = qrcoderes, #edited from qrcode_uuid to qrcoderes to distinguish the two variables.
                logged_in = logged_in,
                logged_in_location = logged_in_location 
            )

    return HttpResponse('Success!')
```

**Models.py**

**UserProfile Model**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    GENDER = (
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    qrcode_uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid4)
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qr_codes', blank=True)

    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    middleName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER)
    birthdate = models.DateField(max_length=200)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    agency = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    deptSec = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    streetHouse = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    purok = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    barangay = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cityMunicipality = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'User Profile'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName + " " + self.middleName + " " + self.lastName

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qrcode_img = qrcode.make(self.qrcode_uuid)
        canvas = Image.new('RGB', (370, 370), 'white')
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
        canvas.paste(qrcode_img)
        fileName = f'qr-code-{self.qrcode_uuid}.png'
        buffer = BytesIO()
        canvas.save(buffer,'PNG')
        self.qr_code.save(fileName, File(buffer), save=False)
        canvas.close()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Logger Model**

```
class Logger(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    qrcode_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    logged_in = models.CharField(max_length=1, default="1")
    logged_in_location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    log_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = 'Logger'

    def __str__(self):
            return self.logged_in_location + " " + self.qrcode_uuid
```

**Ajax.js**

```
function processQRCodeDetails(){

$.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: '/processqrcode/',
      data:{
        qrcoderes: $('#process-qrcoderes').val(),
        logged_in: $('#logged_in').val(),
        logged_in_location: $('#logged_in_location').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
      },
      success: function(data){
        $('#staticBackdrop').modal();
        console.log('Success');
      },
      error: function(data){
        console.log('Error')
      }
    });

}
```

**template.html**

```
<form id="process-qrcoderes-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="process-qrcoderes" id="process-qrcoderes" onchange="processQRCodeDetails(); return false;" autofocus="autofocus">
  <input type="text" name="logged_in" id="logged_in" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="logged_in_location" id="logged_in_location" value="test">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get UserProfile from db and pass it to create method

```
 def processQRCode(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        qrcode_uuid = request.POST['qrcoderes']
        logged_in = request.POST['logged_in']
        logged_in_location = request.POST['logged_in_location']

        # edit: you can get your UserProfile instance by "qrcode_uuid" as well
        # use get_or_create, note that it returns tuple, not instance
        userprofile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(qrcode_uuid=qrcode_uuid)
 
        if created:
            # some additional actions here for newly created UserProfile, filling some fields may be
            
            # recommended naming convention for class attrs in python is underscore_case, not camelCase
            userprofile.firstName = "John"
            userprofile.save()

        Logger.objects.create(
            qrcode_uuid = qrcode_uuid,
            logged_in = logged_in,
            logged_in_location = logged_in_location,
            userprofile=userprofile
        )

    return HttpResponse('Success!')
```

Comment: thanks for the response, `logged_in` is you are logged in to a specific location, just like a manual logbook where you are writing your information as a person.
logged_in is not use in the login authentication of the system. :)

Comment: this also means that `request.user` is not application since the user is not actually log in in the system.

Comment: what I want to achieve is to log all the qrcode_uuid that was scanned via qrcode scanner and linked the `qrcode_uuid` of `Logger,userprofile` to `UserProfile` model  to easily identify the log by not just looking at the` uuid` but with the `UserProfile` like fullname. :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, already did that, but got an error `qrcodemonsys.models.UserProfile.DoesNotExist: UserProfile matching query does not exist.` I am really new in Django, sorry. :)

Comment: The new edits will add/create new data in the `UserProfle` model not in `Logger` model.

Comment: @Markmeplease your Logger model has OneToOne relation with UserProfile model, so to link Logger insntance to UserProfile instance you should create both

Comment: So, there is no way I can fetch the `UserProfile` to `Logger` Model? I thought, django should just generate something like `Select id from UserProfile where qrcode_uuid == POST['qrcoderes']` to fetch the data I want from `UserProfile` and store it in `Logger` model.

Comment: @Markmeplease in current example method get_or_create fetches existing instance of UserProfile and if it does not exist creates it, then, in next few lines, we pass fetched or created instance as arg to the create method of Logger "userprofile=userprofile"

Comment: I tried it, but it mainly create a data to `UserProfile` model where I have nothing to create upon, I only want to create the `Logger` model where the `Logger.userprofile` is equal on the `UserProfile.id` that is based on the `qrcode_uuid` input. also, `UserProfile` is already created ahead of time and the two Models cannot be created at the same time.

Comment: `UserProfile` is like an Identification Card where the `qrcode_uuid` is his/her identification number, once you have created your profile, you use your Identification Card to enter a facility where you need to present the QRcode to be able to enter, the system will just Logged your details in the database and later will be use to for auditing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it accidentally.

I don't know what happened to the `UUIDField` but, got a record which was edited under the `UserProfile` model (has only 3 records in it), unfortunately and fortunately, when I scanned the 3rd record which was edited using the "Save and Continue editing" of django admin, "it work like a charm!" (as everyone call it when it worked :D), so, I proceeded editing the 2 other records and it worked also.

My primarily goal was to just insert the `id` of the `UserProfile` model to `Logger` model to linked the 2 models using the following syntax:

```
# been trying this syntax for ages now. lol. and it was not the problem.
userprofile_id = UserProfile.objects.get(qrcode_uuid=qrcoderes) 

    #Note: Using the .objects.create() method also works now.
    log = Logger(
            userprofile = userprofile_id,
            qrcode_uuid = qrcoderes, #edited from qrcode_uuid to qrcoderes to distinguish the two variables.
            logged_in = logged_in,
            logged_in_location = logged_in_location
        )
    log.save()
```

Note: this was not working, it was giving me an error `UserProfile matching query does not exist.`, even using the `shell`, it is giving me the same error. So, I thought, my syntax was the problem, that's why I posted my problem here.

Maybe, I'll trying to use the `CharField` for the `UUID` if that's makes a difference or if it is compatible for the `UUID`.